# rspec and friendly_id mismatches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, friendly-id

I'm having trouble passing these tests:

```
# user_controller_spec.rb
describe "GET #edit" do
  user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
  it "returns http success" do
    get :edit, params: {id: user.hash_id}
    expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
  end
  it "renders :edit" do
    get :edit, params: {id: user.hash_id}
    expect(response).to render_template :edit
  end
end
```

This outputs:

```
Failures:

1) UsersController when authenticated GET #edit returns http success
 Failure/Error: @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])

 ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
   can't find record with friendly id: "cWLxnN9DS43g"
 # /Users/speasley/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/friendly_id-5.2.3/lib/friendly_id/finder_methods.rb:23:in `find'
 # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:109:in `set_user'
 # /Users/speasley/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rails-controller-testing-1.0.2/lib/rails/controller/testing/template_assertions.rb:61:in `process'
 # /Users/speasley/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/devise-4.4.3/lib/devise/test/controller_helpers.rb:35:in `block in process'
 # /Users/speasley/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/devise-4.4.3/lib/devise/test/controller_helpers.rb:102:in `catch'
 # /Users/speasley/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/devise-4.4.3/lib/devise/test/controller_helpers.rb:102:in `_catch_warden'
 # /Users/speasley/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/devise-4.4.3/lib/devise/test/controller_helpers.rb:35:in `process'
 # /Users/speasley/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rails-controller-testing-1.0.2/lib/rails/controller/testing/integration.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Integration>'
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:132:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

But if I `puts` to compare input/output:

```
# users_controller.rb
before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
...
def set_user
  @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
  puts "#{params[:id]}, @user.hash_id"
end
```

I get a different id instead than the one in the failure message. Should these not match? I cannot figure out why the test is failing at all but comparing these seems to be a logical place to start. Within the `set_user` method, I can `puts` the found user and their attributes but cannot get the test to pass. Any ideas?

Comment: How can you see what `puts` returns if the error is raised before this line?

Comment: It's an rspec failure message, not a Rails error. The spec fails and Rails/ActiveRecord handles it just fine so I can puts.

Comment: Show the whole error message and backtrace

Comment: I've edited my original post, @chumakoff. The weird thing is that the `puts` directly from `set_user` shows that a user is successfully queried (but the `hash_id` mismatches the one in the thrown error).

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `hash_id` as friendly id? Is this the field where user's friendly id is stored?

There is a method that should return the right friendly id value regardless of which field is actually used for it: `friendly_id`.

```
get :edit, params: {id: user.friendly_id}
```

Comment: Yes, `hash_id` is where I am storing the `friendly_id`. So I have set `friendly_id :hash_id`. I tried what you suggested but get the same result.

Comment: Try replacing `user = FactoryBot.create(:user)` with `let(:user) { FactoryBot.create(:user) }`

Comment: No dice. Dang it.